Strong line flickering in viewport
I'm not sure if it was earlier, or I just didn't notice that, but now I see strong flickering of lines in viewport (Blender 4.0.2). Maybe I changed some settings, or there's some anti-aliasing option. Here's a cube:

Blender is running under GTX 1650 Ti card on my laptop. I can only suppose that it happened after one of the NVIDIA driver update. I loaded factory settings in Blender, but that didn't help.

Check in preferences in Viewport section if Smooth wires is turned on:


Thanks. I checked it, and it's the same as on your screenshot. But the problem remains.

Is it a default scene? What is clip start/clip end settings?

Yes, I just run Blender, add several loops to the cube, and that's all I do. I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but "Clip Start = 0.01 m", "Clip End = 1000 m".

Try Clip end 100 m or Clip start 0.1

Thanks. I've done it, but sadly it made no changes.
